# Ангуляр 8. Ошибка при использовании метода сохранения файла

Tags: java, angular

Есть методы в ангуляре:

```js
downloadFile() {
    this._bookService.download().subscribe();
}
```

```js
download(): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get(`http://localhost:8082/api/files/xYRPSxzRc3A.jpg`);
}
```

Метод в сервере (spring boot):

```java
@GetMapping("/files/{filename:.+}")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Resource> getFile(@PathVariable String filename) {
    Resource file = storageService.load(filename);
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getFilename() + "\"").body(file);
}
```

Выдает 200 OK, но потом ошибка:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

ну и файл не скачивается.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш метод get предполагает получения JSON и ошибка вам говорит о том что при получении ответа происходит парсинг тела ответа из JSON в объект. Однако само собой у вас не приходит JSON в ответе.

Почитать про данную историю вы можете тут

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50826531/httpclient-post-tries-to-parse-a-non-json-response

В вашем случае вам нужно корректно составить запрос для того чтобы ответ ожидался в правильном формате. По ссылке есть примеры как проставить корректные заголовки.

Comment: Попробовала следующее: 
`
download(): Observable<any> {
    const httpOptionsGet = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Accept':'application/pdf'
      }),
      'responseType': 'blob' as 'json'
     };
    return this.httpClient.get(`http://localhost:8082/api/files/чек-лист.pdf`, httpOptionsGet);
  }
`
и вот это 
`
 download(fileName): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get(`http://localhost:8082/api/files/чек-лист.pdf`, {responseType: 'blob'});
  }
`
Ошибок теперь нет, но все равно ничего не скачивается

Comment: @АнастасияНовикова так если вам надо скачать этот файл на компьютер, то попросту выкладывайте его ссылку и браузер это сам сделает по нажатию на эту ссылку.